# Javascript / jQuery - Detect Browser Height - Simple Fix?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, height

After I got some help from a couple fellow members suggesting that the solution to my problem here:
[DIV "100%" height, stretch from top DIV to bottom footer to accommodate background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274520/div-100-height-stretch-from-top-div-to-bottom-footer-to-accommodate-backgrou)
was JavaScript / jQuery, I found something online:

http://nicholasbarger.com/2011/08/04/jquery-makes-100-height-so-much-easier/

However, I need some customizing. At the moment it does what I need it to do. When I have a little content, it'll push my DIV to the entire height of the browser.

But when I have MORE content, the content keeps going, but the DIV doesnt expand.

**How can I customize the following script so it detects that if there's enough content it doesn't need to adjust the height?**

```
<script>
//Initial load of page
$(document).ready(sizeContent);

//Every resize of window
$(window).resize(sizeContent);

//Dynamically assign height
function sizeContent() {
    var newHeight = $("html").height() - $("#header").height() - $("#content-header").height()- $("#footer-wrapper").height() + 6 + "px";
    $("#content").css("height", newHeight);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Consider looking in the CSS property "max-height". I'm not 100% convinced jQuery is the right solution for defining presentation in this instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function sizeContent() {
    var html = $("html").height(),
        content = $("#content").height(),
        header = $("#header").height(),
        contentHeader = $("#content-header").height(),
        footerWrapper = $("#footer-wrapper").height(),
        availableSpace = html - header - contentHeader - footerWrapper;

    if (content < availableSpace) {
        $("#content").css("height", availableSpace + 6 + "px");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Andreas, thanks for the comment! It allowed the div to expand when there is enough content, but when there isnt enough content it doesnt do the calculation. Close though! Maybe its missing something minor?

Comment: Did you check the individual heights? Currently I can't think of any problems with this part of code... Either `content` is smaller (change the height) or bigger (do nothing) then `availableSpace`

Comment: Ups, missed the `+ 6 + "px"` part... :(

Comment: i just checked all the heights, and everything is ok. I also added the + 6 + "px" part and its still the same. Andreas - will it work better / less troublesome if exact pixel numbers were put in, instead of DIV IDs? It works fine when theres enough content to push the DIV, but didnt calculate the available space when there isnt enough. Thanks!

Comment: Also - I really appreciate your help. Ive been looking for a solution for so long and we're so close!! Thanks!

Note: Right now my #content DIV does not have any height specified, because i intended it to expand as the content varies from page to page. Should there be some height in the #content?

Comment: Could you set up an example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) - `.height()` will get the current height of the element regardless of any height which is specified by a style attribute or css rule.

Comment: Hi Andreas - Thanks! Here. I know it is bizarre how the layout is coded, but its a very graphic-heavy, graphic-based design and involved a lot of transparency images. thats why it is like that. http://jsfiddle.net/e5u38/

Comment: Andreas - does your footer stick to the bottom of the browser when you have less content, e.g. 2 rows of "Apple"? It doesnt for me - it pushes up to the top, right after where apples are finished. Weird...http://img442.imageshack.us/img442/1108/footerj.jpg

Comment: Andreas - thats very interesting. I understand what is happening now. Once the window resizes the footer immediately goes to the bottom, which is perfect! However, is there some way the script can be written so the footer stays at the bottom after refresh? (so it doesnt need window resize to stay at bottom) That's the last requirement - otherwise, this is perfection. Thank you!

Comment: Did you remove the `$(document).ready(sizeContent);` if so, add it back into the script.

Comment: Perfect!!! Thank you very much Andreas!! It works perfectly now. That was what was missing. I included both `$(document).ready(sizeContent);` and `$(window).resize(sizeContent);` and now it works perfect! it sticks to bottom of footer and it also resizes if someone decides to resize their browser. The #content won't shrink again but hey, it doesnt matter, as long as it enlarges to cover the gap! Thank you very much Andreas - you saved my life! :-)

Comment: Hi @Andreas, would you happen to know why the script does not work with the Opera browser? I've been testing it in a couple browsers, it seems Opera is the only one with problem, it works perfectly fine in IE, FF, Chrome, and Safari. Thank you @Andreas!

Comment: Hi @Andreas, thanks. I did further testing and you are right, it does appear generally the same as in Chrome. I actually had something else on my page that wasnt very friendly on Opera, ive written a code just for Opera browser to fix that. However, it seems Opera Mobile browser isnt very friendly either. But its not a big deal, cant please everyone! It even works fine in Firefox mobile and Default android browser, only Opera Mobile. Awkwardly, this weird bug only shows on the homepage, so whatever, i'll just use more content to push the homepage. Thanks for all your help @Andreas!!